# Ubuntu 13.04: Audio does not work on HP Probook 4530s

Tags: 13.04, sound, laptop, hp

I'm having a problem with the build in audio of my HP ProBook 4530s laptop (with Ubuntu 13.04), there is no sound at all. If I connect a USB headphone, the headphone does work correctly. So I guess the problem is related to driver for the audio chip. The audio chip detected by `lspci` is:

```
Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04
```

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: STAC92xx Analog [STAC92xx Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

cat /proc/asound/version
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k3.8.0-26-generic.

stephan@stephan-HP-ProBook-4530s:~$ head -n 1 /proc/asound/card*/codec#*
==> /proc/asound/card0/codec#0 <==
Codec: IDT 92HD87B1/3

==> /proc/asound/card0/codec#3 <==
Codec: Intel CougarPoint HDMI
```

Any ideas on how to get the audio working? The build in audio of this laptop never worked on Ubuntu, but in Windows it used to work fine.

Comment: Have you tried this instruction: [HDAISHT](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto)